# Naming convention issues when using codeigniter in windows and linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have made a web application in **codeigniter** framework. I was developing the app on a Windows machine and the final version runs perfectly well on the same (i.e windows, *wamp to be precise*).
Now i need to deploy the app on a ubuntu server. After the initial login required in the app, it does not display any other page.On inspecting the console, I found this

```
[09:08:37.255] GET http://localhost/sac.org/index.php/member [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 17ms]
```

I think this is a very common problem, as is evident from these questions:

[codeigniter framework not working on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006340/codeigniter-web-app-is-not-working-with-the-linux-but-here-on-windows-is-fine)

[Windows code not working on linux](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/124792/#617664)

[codeigniter upload not working on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308212/codeigniter-upload-not-working-on-linux)

and here  too [Codeigniter issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1805)

and many more. The answers mentioned in these threads are not working for me.
Is there some way to solve this issue?

My code sample is

```
<?php
class member extends CI_Controller{
    public $data1 = "";
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('table');      
        $this->load->model('membermodel');
        $this->data1 = $this->membermodel->getYearList();
    }
    private function accesscheck(){
        $privilege = $this->session->userdata('privilege');
        if($privilege=='2'||$privilege=='1'){
            return "True";
        }

    }

    public function index(){
        echo phpinfo();
        die();
        if($this->accesscheck()){
        $data = array('years'=>$this->membermodel->getYearList());
        $notifications = $this->membermodel->numberOfNotifications();
        $this->session->set_userdata('notifications',$notifications);
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('members/home',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}

    public function year($year){
        if($this->accesscheck()){

            $this->getTable($year,"FullList");


    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}

    public function positive($year){
        if($this->accesscheck()){
            $this->gettable($year,"positive");
        }else{
            $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
        }
    }
    public function negative($year){
                if($this->accesscheck()){

                    $this->getTable($year,"negative");

}
    else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
    public function neutral($year){
                if($this->accesscheck()){
            $this->getTable($year,"neutral");


    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}

    public function registered($year){
                if($this->accesscheck()){

                    $this->gettable($year,"register");

    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
    public function uncontacted($year){
                        if($this->accesscheck()){
            $this->getTable($year,"uncontacted");

    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
    public function unsearched($year){
                        if($this->accesscheck()){
            $this->getTable($year,"unsearched");


    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
    public function notfound($year){
                                if($this->accesscheck()){

                $this->gettable($year,"notFound");


    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
public function Paid($year){
    if($this->accessCheck()){

                    $this->getTable($year,"Paid");


    }else{
    $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}}
public function getProfile(){
    $id=$this->input->get('id');
    $data = $this->membermodel->getPrimaryInfo($id);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
public function getTable($year,$list){
    $this->data1 = $this->membermodel->getYearList();
        if(in_array(array('alumSince'=>$year),$this->data1)){// think of a get around
            $data['table'] = $this->membermodel->getTable($year,$list);
            $data['year'] = $year;
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/menu');
            $this->load->view('members/fullList',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/badParam');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}


public function search(){

        if($this->session->userdata('privilege')){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('members/search');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }

    public function generate_result(){


        if($this->session->userdata('privilege')){
            $data = $this->membermodel->search();

                        if($data){
                            $this->load->view('templates/header');
                            $this->load->view('templates/menu');
                            $this->load->view('members/search_result',$data);
                            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                        }



        }else{
            $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
}

}

public function updateProfile(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){

            if($msg = $this->membermodel->updateProfile()){
                header('Refresh:2,url='.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);//security issues here
                echo $msg;
            }
        }

    }else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }


}

public function updateSearch(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
        $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
        $search = $this->input->get('search');
        $result = $this->membermodel->updateSearch($alumid,$search);
            echo $result;
        }
        else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }
}
public function updateResponse(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
        $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
        $response = $this->input->get('response');
        $result = $this->membermodel->updateResponse($alumid,$response);
            echo $result;
        }
        else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }
}
public function updatePayment(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
            $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
            $dateofpayment = $this->input->get('dateofpayment');
            $referenceNo =  $this->input->get('referenceNo');
            $paymentAmt = $this->input->get('paymentAmt');
            $remarks = $this->input->get('remarks');
            $result = $this->membermodel->updatePayment($alumid,$dateofpayment,$referenceNo,$paymentAmt,$remarks);

                echo $result;




    }else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }
}
public function updateRegister(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
            $register  = $this->input->get('register');
            $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
            $result = $this->membermodel->updateRegister($alumid,$register);

                echo $result;




    }else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');
    }
}
public function addCallDetail(){
    $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');
    echo $this->membermodel->addCallDetail($alumid,$date,$time);
}

public function updateCall(){
        $remarks = $this->input->get('remarks');
        $nextdate = $this->input->get('nextdate');
        $nexttime = $this->input->get('nexttime');
        $callid = $this->input->get('callid');
        $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
        echo $this->membermodel->updateCall($remarks,$nextdate,$nexttime,$callid,$alumid);

}
public function updateMember(){
        $name = $this->input->get('name');
        $age = $this->input->get('age');
        $gender = $this->input->get('gender');
        $relationship = $this->input->get('relationship');
        $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
        echo $this->membermodel->updateMember($name,$age,$gender,$relationship,$alumid);

}
public function removeAccompaniant(){
        $memberid = $this->input->get('id');
        $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');
        echo $this->membermodel->removeAccompaniant($memberid,$alumid);

}
public function updateRemark(){
    $remark = $this->input->get('remark');
    $alumid = $this->input->get('alumid');

    echo $this->membermodel->updateRemark($alumid,$remark);
}


public function getNetworkingSummary($year){

    $userid = $this->membermodel->getUserId();
    if($data =  $this->membermodel->getNetworkingSummary($userid,$year))
        echo json_encode($data);

        //echo json_encode($data['msg']="boo");
}
public function getNotifications(){
    if($this->accessCheck()){
        $data['result'] = $this->membermodel->getNotifications();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('templates/dummyMember',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('templates/accessErr');

    }

}
public function notificationStatus(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');

    $this->membermodel->updateNotificationStatus($id);

}

}
?>
```

Comment: Check your `error_log` file generated by your webserver if you want to know what the error is. Getting a 500 Internal server error means something within your code or server is wrong. Could be from folder permission to code errors to a variety of things which is why you must check the `error_log`.

Comment: Open your `index.php` file in the root of your CI install, near the top of the file, turn on error reporting by changing the environment constant, then reload the page. (You may need to add the `ini_set('display_errors','on');` line.). You should see a more detailed error message then.

Comment: @Prix , I saw the error log it says a syntax error in one of my file,  it says unexpected '[' in  " switch ($query->row_array()['search']) {" . However there is no such error on windows . Is this due to different php versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by Prix, I checked my error log and found that the problem was due to syntax error.
I was using **Function array dereferencing** which has been added in PHP 5.4.0  but my server was running PHP 5.2.

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912233/php-array-syntax-parse-error-left-square-bracket)

The solution worked. I had to resort to this method rather than upgrading my PHP version because the server is running UBUNTU 12.04 which has no repos for PHP 5.4 .