# Codeigniter file names and loading helpers under Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

Some of you might think that this question was already asked hundred of times, still I haven't found an answer to the specific problem I have.

I have read these topics but none of them answers the question I have:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1805

[codeigniter upload not working on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308212/codeigniter-upload-not-working-on-linux)

[Codeigniter web app is not working with the linux but here on windows is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006340/codeigniter-web-app-is-not-working-with-the-linux-but-here-on-windows-is-fine)

[Naming convention issues when using codeigniter in windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675750/naming-convention-issues-when-using-codeigniter-in-windows-and-linux)

I am developing a PHP application. My test server at home runs Windows, the stage server runs Ubuntu (Amazon AWS).

1. My application worked flawlessly until I needed to create a helper:

   ```
   MY_form_helper.php
   ```

   In that helper I needed to overwrite this:

   ```
   function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
       {
           if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
           {
               if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
               {
                   return $default;
               }

               return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);
           }

           return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
       }
   ```

   with this:

   ```
               function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
       {
           if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
           {
               if (isset($_POST[$field]))
               {
                   return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);

               }
               if (isset($_GET[$field]))
               {
                   return form_prep($_GET[$field], $field);

               }
                   return $default;

           }

           return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
       }
   ```

So I saved the changes to the

```
     MY_form_helper.php
```

Tested it all on windows and great everything works. All you PHP gurus probably know what happens now, I upload to linux server and errors :)

First error I get this:

```
    An Error Was Encountered

    Unable to load the requested file: helpers/my_form_helper.php
```

Well ok, linux is case sensitive so I have changed all the upper case file names to the lower case ones. After doing that I was greeted by blank page.

Side note: I have libraries that have capitalised first letter in name (for example I use flexi_auth library) and it always worked on the server. I dont know why now, as surely it should have failed on the Linux because of the capital letters in file names - would be great if someone could explain.

I have changed config in my index.php to display all the errors by adding

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

here:

```
    if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
    {
        switch (ENVIRONMENT)
        {
            case 'development':
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            break;

            case 'testing':
            case 'production':
                error_reporting(0);
            break;

            default:
                exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
        }
    }
```

I reload the page and now I can see that there is fatal error:

```
    Fatal error: Cannot redeclare set_value() (previously declared in /var/www/html/stage/bik/system/helpers/form_helper.php:675) in /var/www/html/stage/bik/application/helpers/my_form_helper.php on line 5
```

And here is where I am stuck. I did a big no-no and edited the form_helper in the core system files of CI with my code. I needed it all to work as I have people testing the whole thing and I couldn't have them wait.

**So could someone explain to me what is going on?** I am relatively new to Linux having always used Windows machines and servers. But I want to go with the flow and use Linux as cool kids do.

2. Here are few more bits that might help

MY_form_helper file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 



function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
{
    if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);

        }
        if (isset($_GET[$field]))
        {
            return form_prep($_GET[$field], $field);

        }
            return $default;

    }

    return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
}
```

This is how I load it in controller:

```
$this->load->helper('MY_form_helper');
```

I have changed both capital letter to lower case when moving it to linux server.

And now something that boggles my mind, I have created MY_Input library and I am loading it from core folder in CI Appliaction folder. This thing has upper case letters in name and it works on the Linux server.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Input extends CI_Input {


function save_query($query_array){

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->db->insert('ci_query', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));

    return $CI->db->insert_id();        

}


function load_query($query_id){

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $rows = $CI->db->get_where('ci_query', array('queryid' => $query_id))->result();

    if (isset($rows[0])) {
        parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);

    }

}


    }
```

I am still learning PHP and I do not get many things and I do not have much experience so I really appreciate all the help anyone can give me.

I hope I made clear what I need answering. Thank you to whomever who is willing to share their knowledge with me!

Comment: Hi. I think you can wrap the function into the class

Comment: Hi volkinc - as in `class MY_form_helper extends ...` is there a CI_helper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can wrap the function into the class

```
class MY_form_helper{
static function  set_value($field = '', $default = '')
    {
        if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$field]))
            {
                return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);

            }
            if (isset($_GET[$field]))
            {
                return form_prep($_GET[$field], $field);

            }
                return $default;

        }

        return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
    }
}
```

and you will be able to call it like:

```
MY_form_helper::set_value($field, $default);
```

or you need to use namespaces but this is longer

Comment: OK Thanks - I will try it now and report back!

Comment: according the error that you gave, it's just the global functions  that php cannot redeclare. the quick approach wrap your function into the class as a static method.

Comment: @PawelKosi You now have enough rep to vote up answers & questions that you think are "useful" by clicking on the up arrow/triangle by the vote count. This lets others know the post is useful. Also (no beer, but) the poster gets some rep & sometimes tag badge credit.